# Enable customers to make payment via cc after order is placed

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, payment-gateway

Can someone guide me on how to enable customers to pay via cc for orders already placed?

In this case, a customer can place an order and select wire transfer but I want to give them the possibility to make payment via credit card after.
I already made an extension to add the custom page which loads the order with status new in customer dashboard.

Now, I want when they click "Make Payment" to be redirected either to a page where they can enter the cc details or.. do I need to recreate the checkout/onepage process?

In makepaymentAction I grabbed the order id so my link looks like: "localhost/pendingpayment/sales_order/makepayment/order_id/1228/" [image: makepaymentimg]

Any help will greatly be appreciated!
Thank you!

**--EDIT--**

The credit card payment is based on Magento's credit card payment template and the payment is made through Firstdata payment gateway api.

As I said, what I want is when a user does not complete the payment or if he selects wire transfer for example, to see this order in account dashboard (achieved that already) and the Make Payment button should take him to either a page where the credit card form template is loaded or a popup and a "Pay" button.

Can I mimic the Place Order Now button action to update the order (status) and save/process the payment?

[image]

Comment: it depends on what kind of payment portal you are using. You will have to create the call to the payment portal yourself. Checkout the module that creates the payment in the checkout should give you some hind as to how to approach this. But without further info or a concrete issue it's hard to give a good answer

Comment: I've edited the question but there isn't much to explain as I am looking for a way to display a page or a popup with the payment method and a call to action button that will... do the same thing it does the Place Order Now button.

Comment: Did you find any proven solution for this.I am also actively looking for this kind of solution.If you did please can you describe here